# RMS value of a line to neutral voltage on a three phase inverter

Tags: inverter, three-phase, rms

Basically, I feel like this is an incredibly simple thing, but my brain is stuck on it for hours now, and I can't find the answer anywhere.

How do I find the RMS value of the signal shown, assuming all of the "steps" are of the equal duration? Do I have to do an integral from zero to T (but then what would the function inside look like?) like usual, because it really feels like there's some incredibly simple thing I'm missing here?

[image]

I should also write what I tried, but it doesn't seem right at all:

$$Ua0rms=\sqrt\frac{{((\frac{Uo}{3})^2+(\frac{2Uo}{3})^2+(\frac{Uo}{3})^2)*\frac{T}{6}}}{T}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual definition of RMS voltage should lead you to the right thing to integrate

$$
Vrms = \sqrt{\frac1T\int_0^T V(t)^{2}}dt\,.
$$

what you wrote is actually fine... but it is only half you don't have the amounts from the part that is negative since it is identical to the positive I guess your T/6 common factor is missing a two for your calculation to be correct, assuming that each rectangle is T/3 on the bottom is correct.

if you develop that I get
$$
\frac{2Uo^2}{9}
$$

you can just simplify the Ts and add up the Uo squared factors, even the six cancels out.

edit: changed the Vrms formula to be a bit easier to understand.